# Hyundai Tucson Diesel 2.0 2008 - Difficulty Starting

Tags: engine, starting, diesel, hyundai

Hyundai Tucson Diesel 2.0 2008 and takes at least 4-5 attempts to start before it idles badly for about 10 seconds and then is fine. Doesn't die at the traffic lights, no problems at all otherwise. Just starts badly. Could it be the Cam sensor? Fuel pump? Throttle position sensor?  All help taken!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your glow plugs are on their way out or you are not letting them get up to temperature prior to starting the engine. Once the engine is running, it warms up and it's fine. You stop at a light and all is normal.